# How to use event listeners inside react render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

In my code, I want to display the value on the screen. When that value changes it should display the changed value. But that is not happening in my code. I thought that I should add an event listener. But I can't understand how to add it. In this code, I have used web workers.

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import ReactCountdownClock from "react-countdown-clock";
import worker from "./worker.js";
import WebWorker from "./workerSetup";
import "./App.css";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.value = 0;
    this.handleWebWorker = this.handleWebWorker.bind(this);
  }



  handleWebWorker = () => {
    let count = 10;
    this.worker = new WebWorker(worker);
    this.worker.postMessage(count);

    this.worker.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
      this.value = event.data;
      console.log("Tester 3", this.value);
    })
  }


  render() {

    
    return (
      <div className="App-bottom">
        <button onClick={this.handleWebWorker}>Click me</button>
        <h1>{this.value}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**worker.js**

```
export default () => {
  self.onmessage = function (e){
      console.log("Tester 2",e.data);
      let x=e.data;
      
      while(x>0){
          x--; 
          postMessage(x);

      }
      
  }


  
};
```

Comment: instead of using `this.value`, try setting it as a state and in render display it as `this,state.value`. Changing the class variable doesn't trigger a rerender. You have to use state for that

Comment: I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: How did you try? Can you please add the code on what you tried and what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Vishnu actually I couldn't code since I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I've changed up some of your method/variable names, but this should work for what you are attempting to do:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-neumann-xh78p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I didn't use the webWorker - I just initialized the state in the constructor() method.

Comment: Thanks.But I actually want to change the value without clicking the button

Comment: Do not post links to code on external websites unless you also include ***all*** of the code in your answer.  If that link dies, this answer becomes useless.